# How to convert lookup tables from txt to JSON

Tags: python, json, regex, string, lookup-tables

I have this `.txt` file which I need to convert to JSON. There are a lot of three dimensional lookup tables. I can change equal sign to colons, add quotes to the names of parameters etc.

What I need is to remove those `%Z_AXIS(...` and change it to square brackets, but I need to distinguish if the `%Z_AXIS` is the first one after parameters (then I need to add double square brackets `[[`), if the `%Z_AXIS` is the last one (then I need to add double square brackets `]]`) or if it is somewhere in between (then I need to add `],[`)

```
p3_foo_Y_unit = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; %arbitrary size
p3_foo_X_unit = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]; %arbitrary size
p3_foo_unit = [ % p3_foo_X_unit number of columns, p3_foo_Y_unit: number of rows, number of Z_AXIS tag arbitrary, data arbitrary
%Z_AXIS(0.3)
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
%Z_AXIS(0.5)
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
%Z_AXIS(0.7)
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
%Z_AXIS(0.9)
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
%Z_AXIS(1.1)
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
%Z_AXIS(1.3)
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
%Z_AXIS(1.5)
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;];
```

So it would look somehow like this:

```
p3_foo_Y_unit = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
p3_foo_X_unit = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
p3_foo_unit = [[
    data
    ],[
    data
    ],[
    data
    ],[
    data
    ],[
    data
    ],[
    data
    ],[
    data]],
```

I am using this (pseudo code)

```
with open(txt_file, "r") as f_in:
    m_string = f_in.read()
    m_string = re.sub(r'%[a-zA-Z]_AXIS[a-zA-Z0-9():@ _.]+', "],[", str(m_string))
```

Comment: since your goal is json, just define how your txt maps to json, no need provide a middle data format.

Comment: I'm not sure if you really need just brackets? because json-format is "key": "value" pairs, and brackets can give just an Array. Thus, you also need "key" assignment somewhere in order to have proper json!. I suppose, your X, Y axes numbers are considered to become keys for certain row & column... So, I assume that your TODO request here is not what you really need. And as alternative you can read raw by raw txt - splitting lines to Dictionary & then dump it to json-string. Or get your Table from source to DataFrame (without intermediate txt-file) & apply its "to_json" method in Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following piece of code does the exact you want

```py
import re


with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    content = f.read()

    # Remove all like '%arbitrary size'
    content = re.sub(r"];.*?$", "];", content, flags=re.MULTILINE)

    # Set open braces
    content = re.sub(r"=\s*\[\s*%.*?%\w_AXIS\([\d.]+\)", "= [[", content, flags=re.DOTALL)

    # Set close/open braces
    content = re.sub(r"%\w_AXIS\([\d.]+\)", "], [", content, flags=re.DOTALL)

    # Set close braces
    content = re.sub(r"];$", "]]", content, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

After execution, the `content` will contain the following value

```
p3_foo_Y_unit = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
p3_foo_X_unit = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
p3_foo_unit = [[
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
], [
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
], [
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
], [
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
], [
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
], [
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
], [
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that you meant to replace last occurrence with "]]" as that would leave out the last array. It has a "]" at end of file already, do you just want that to be "]]" ? Here is js code that will produce what I believe you have asked for. You can change to specify the input/output file.

```
//  convert txt file as specified and create new textfile as per required format

const cl = (...args) => console.log(...args);
const fs = require("fs");

// cnvTxt is used to find and replace the "%Z_AXIS(x,y)" (12 char) with specified new text
const cnvTxt = (txt, txtnew) =>
  txt.substring(0, a) + txtnew + txt.substring(a + 12);
const oldTxt = "%Z_AXIS";
const firstNewTxt = "[[";
const secondNewTxt = "],[";
const inputFile = "z.txt"; // copied your txt to z.txt
const outputFile = "zoutput.txt";

let txt1 = fs.readFileSync(inputFile, "utf8");
let txt2 = txt1;

let a = txt1.indexOf(oldTxt); // first occurence position

txt2 = cnvTxt(txt2, firstNewTxt); // first replacement
let isZ = true;
while (isZ) {
  a = txt2.indexOf(oldTxt);
  if (a === -1) {
    isZ = false;
  } else {
    txt2 = cnvTxt(txt2, secondNewTxt);
  }
}

// Write data in 'Output.txt' .
let data = txt2;
fs.writeFile("zoutput.txt", data, (err) => {
  // In case of a error throw err.
  if (err) throw err;
});
cl("Output written to zoutput.txt");
```